# Passing arguments to docker swarm containers

Tags: docker, parameter-passing, containers, docker-swarm

I have three servers in a Docker Swarm cluster (1 master and 2 nodes).

I want to start containers that execute a command which has an incremental value.

Doing that from bash simply using Docker was very easy:

```
for i in `seq 1 6`; 
  do 
    sudo docker run --cpuset-cpus="$i" -d -v /tmp/out:/data_out -t -i image /binary $i 
  done
```

As you can see I'm starting several containers each one using a specific CPU id and passing the same id as argument to a `binary` which is within the container.

How can I do the same but using my Docker Swarm cluster?

Thank you